# onclick of image from image list display the clicked image in a main div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I have achieved multiple file uploads and Preview for all file uploaded images before it is saved to database in yii using jquery.

But I also need a condition

1. required at max 3 and minimun 1 file uploads. I did search but found which matches my requirement
2. want to reuse the code  something as foreach for multiple uploads .
3. on click of image (id's blah1, blah2) display that image in  first div -- to preview

I did try but found not working.

view

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var preview = $("#blah");
  var preview1 = $("#blah1");
   var preview2 = $("#blah2");

   $("#input").change(function(event){
   var input = $(event.currentTarget);
    var file = input[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e){
   image_base64 = e.target.result;
   preview.attr("src", image_base64);

     };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });

    $("#imgInput1").change(function(event){
   var input = $(event.currentTarget);
  var file = input[0].files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e){
   image_base64 = e.target.result;
   preview1.attr("src", image_base64);

   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });

  $("#imgInput1").click(function(event){
   var input = $(event.currentTarget);
     var file = input[0].files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
   image_base64 = e.target.result;
   preview.attr("src", image_base64);

   };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });

  $("#imgInput2").change(function(event){
    var input = $(event.currentTarget);
    var file = input[0].files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e){
   image_base64 = e.target.result;
   preview2.attr("src", image_base64);

};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

 });


</script>

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',array(
  'id'=>'edit_form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
 'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
   )); ?>

  <div class="product">
     <div class="imgdiv">
  <img id="blah" class="i1" src="#" width="115px" height="120px"/>
      <img id="blah1" class="i2" src="#" width="50px" height="20px"/>
      <img id="blah2" class="i3" src="#" width="50px" height="20px"/>
    </div>      
    <div class="title4">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pimg'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'pimg',array('id'=>'imgInput',)); ?>

            <?php echo $form->error($model,'pimg'); ?>
    </div>  

     <div class="title4">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pimg'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'pimg',array('id'=>'imgInput1',)); ?>

            <?php echo $form->error($model,'pimg'); ?>
    </div>  

     <div class="title4">
     <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pimg'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'pimg',array('id'=>'imgInput2',)); ?>

            <?php echo $form->error($model,'pimg'); ?>
    </div>  


  </div>

 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Can any one help me to figure out the problem PLEASE HELP! Let me know if any among you know ........ Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**Condition 1**

```
**1)* required at max 3 and minimun 1 file uploads.
```

If you are using **CMultiFileUpload** for uploading the files in the yii then you can use the **max** attribute to tell the maximum no. of files you can upload. Click [max](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMultiFileUpload#max-detail)

**Second THING**

If you want to set the minimum no. of files as 1 then **in the rules you can define that attribute as required**